# removeview() doesn't remove android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, hide

I have a layout (main) that when i click on a button it shows a RelativeLayout (newLayout) with a textview and a edittext. But when i want to leave that RelativeLayout (clicking on some button), it doesn´t dissappear.
My code is this:

When I click on the button, this is the code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_hide:
            RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.atraccion_layout);
            RelativeLayout newLayout= (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.newLayout, null);     
            main.addView(newLayout);
        default: 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }           

}
```

Then when I click over another button, my code is:

```
public void close(View v){
    RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.atraccion_layout);
    RelativeLayout newLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.newLayout, null);
    main.removeView(comentarLayout);
    main.forceLayout();
}
```

But the newLayout is still there.

Tried also:

```
((RelativeLayout)v.getParent()).removeView(v);

main.removeView((View)v.getParent());

newLayout.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);

newLayout.setVisibility(v.GONE);

((RelativeLayout)newLayout.getParent()).forceLayout();

((RelativeLayout)newLayout.getParent()).removeView(comentarLayout);
```

Without success.

Can someone help me why isnt it removing the layout?

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use a fragment?

Comment: may be it was a solution, but with the solution I found I´m ok. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by defining class atributes whith those layers

```
public class ActivityClass extends Activity{
    private RelativeLayout main;
    private RelativeLayout newLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle b){...}
    ...

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_hide:
            main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.atraccion_layout);
            newLayout= (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.newLayout, null);     
            main.addView(newLayout);
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void close(View v){
        main.removeView(newLayout);
        main.forceLayout();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any view transitions, try ending them using `(view.getParent() as ViewGroup).endViewTransition(view)`